# Custom Field not working in value get_the_content?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

`

```
$metadescription = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55, '');

add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description', '$metadescription', true);`
```

but output is $metadescription

anyone help me please

`$metadescription = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55, '');

add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description', '$metadescription', true);``

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code:

For the variable, you don't need to use `''` for that.

```
$metadescription = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55, '');

add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description', $metadescription , true);
```

Comment: not working for removing ''

Comment: Where you have added this code? Can you please add it in your question?

Comment: Themes functions.php

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `get_the_content` is returning the content you want and `$meta_description` isn't null.

Try This:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description', '' . $meta_description . '', true);
```

Comment: output is blank

Comment: tell me where are you using this code? is it in the post loop? first, try to make `get_the_content()` working.

Comment: Themes functions.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the best option, please try this.

```
global $post;
$metadescription = wp_trim_words( apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content), 55, '');
add_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_description',$metadescription, true);
```

Comment: output is still blank